# Galilean to Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I happened to come across a derivation of the Lorentz Transformation stemming from the Galilean Transformation. In two frames $S$ and $S'$ where the position and time coordinates for the frames are $(x,t)$ and $(x',t')$ respectively,the derivation assumed that $x'$ would be $k(x-vt)$. The further derivation invoked the second postulate of the Special Theory of Relativity and we eventually got to the Lorentz Transformation Equation-that's just math I can very well comprehend.
What I don't understand, however, is what gave us the liberty to assume that $x'$ would be a multiple of $x-vt$. There could have been another dimensionally consistent equation, for example $x' = k(\frac{x^4}{v^3t^3}-vt)$, right?

Answer (score 2):

The Lorentz transformation is a transform between inertial frames. That means that an object which does not accelerate in one frame must not accelerate in other frames also. In geometric terms such transforms map straight lines to straight lines. Such transforms are called affine transforms, and if you fix the origins to coincide then the transformation is linear.  That excludes transformations like the one you mention.